# Does the Diophantine equation $a/b + c/d = e/f$ have a solution for coprime denominators?

Tags: prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

Does the Diophantine equation $\frac a b + \frac c d = \frac e f$ have a solution where:

- The denominators are pairwise coprime and $> 1$
- The numerators are not exact multiples of the denominators, so each fraction is not an integer.

I suppose it can be formulated as $adf + cbf = ebd$ with the same conditions.

Comment: The left side is a multiple of $f$. So the right side must be also. But $b$ and $d$ are coprime to $f$. Therefore...

Comment: Do you mean $\text{gcd}(b, d, f)$ is $1$, or that the denominators are pairwise coprime?

Comment: Pairwise. I'll clarify.

Comment: @MJD Ah, I see. Therefore $e$ must be a multiple of $f$. Now I'm curious whether $\frac a b + \frac c d = e$ has a solution, but to be fair that's a separate question.

Comment: Then you would have $ad =ebd - bc$ and the right side is a multiple of $b$, therefore...

Comment: Wow, it's been too long since I did math. Thanks for making the problem obvious for me. At least, it confirms my gut instinct about the answers so there's that. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I ran a brute force search, but I realized that the solution is pretty straight-forward. Suppose there exists some $6$-tuple that satisfies your constraints. Then, as you state, $adf + cbf = ebd$. Therefore, $f \mid ebd$. But, $(d, f) = 1$ and $(b, f) = 1$, so $f \mid e$, but this violates your constraint, leading to a contradiction.

Hence, there are no solutions.