# Does the Diophantine equation $a/b + c/d = e$ have a solution for coprime denominators?

Tags: prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

(This is a followup question to [$\frac a b + \frac c d = \frac e f$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1939528) which has a straightforward answer.)

Does the Diophantine equation $\frac a b + \frac c d = e$ have a solution where:

- The denominators are coprime and $> 1$
- The numerators are not exact multiples of the denominators, so each fraction is not an integer.

It can be formulated as $ad + cb = ebd$ with the same conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Reduce both fractions until $(a,b)=(c,d)=1$. This keeps the coprimality of $b$ and $d$. You cannot end up with $d=1$ or $b=1$ otherwise the second condition would be not fulfilled. Then $d$ must divide $cb$, which is impossible because it is $>1$ and coprime with both.

Comment: Both good answers; this one explained a bit more which was helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

No; write $a/b$ in simplest terms. We have
$$
\frac ab = \frac{de - c}d,
$$
but then $b \mid d$.

Comment: I'm sorry to be slow, but why does that mean $b \mid d$? Why doesn't the subtraction introduce the possibility of the right side being divisible by $b$?

Comment: @jnm2: Because you may write that equality of fractions as $ad = b (de - c)$, so $b \mid ad$, and since $(a,b)=1$ it follows that $b \mid d$.